# Sharepoint 2010 list view slow when including people/group field

Tags: list-view, view

We have a custom list that contains about 20 or so fields. 4 of these fields are person fields. Whenever we create a view that displays any person fields, the view is extremely slow to load; 20 seconds, vs. 1 or 2 seconds.

Any ideas on why this might be and how to fix?

Comment: Anecdotally, I've seen lists load slowly with people/group fields that are set to show presense information, changing the field output to just Name speeds it up.

Comment: We've tried that, but unfortunately it's had no effect.

Answer (score -1):

Try to run the maintenance job on the content database of the web application.

Comment: Can you extend this answer with more details about how to do that?